# SQL / Impala : How to create a column using the existing column

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table like below:

```
id  |  field_A  |  field_B  
----------------------------
1   |   Brown   |  Black
2   |   Blue    |  White
3   |   Red     |  Black
```

I need to create a `field_C` with the logic:

```
if (field_A is not null):
    field_C = field_A
else:
    field_C = field_B
```

Can this be done using SQL/Impala queries? If so, what should be the proper approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `impala` supports `case`:

```
selec id, field_a, field_b,
      case when field_a is not null then field_a
           else field_b
      end as field_c
from yourtable
```